# use date string in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2021-08-20']}, dtype="datetime64[ns]")

df["date"] = df["date"].astype("object")
>>> df
                  date
0  2021-08-20 00:00:00
```

I want to delete 00:00:00.

```
def date_func(value)
    print(type(value))
    #TODO: delete 00:00:00
    return value

df["date"] = df["date"].apply(date_func)
<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
```

original data is object type but date_func method get Timestamp. why??

```
>>> df.dtypes
date    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

and type changed from object type to datetime64[ns].
I think dataframe data type changed automatically too often.

How to remove 00:00:00 in function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2021-08-20']}, dtype="datetime64[ns]")

df["date"] = df["date"].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d').astype("object")
```

Comment: When I read data using read_excel(file_name, dtype="object"), sometimes the type was object and sometimes it was datetime64[ns]. is it possible to narrow it down to one type?

Comment: @afternoon_drinker, plaese use `pd.read_excel('file_name.xlsx', dtype=str) `  not `object` and your data is clean at the outset then, if you have limited columns `pd.read_excel('file_name.xlsx', converters={'col1':str,'date':str})`

Comment: It was not the same Excel file, but what appeared to be the same value could be of a different type.
What is the difference between dtype="object" and dtype=str?

Answer (score 0):

just don't define the dtype and convert it after reading the data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2021-08-20']})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below with the function ...

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2021-08-20']}, dtype="datetime64[ns]")
>>> def convert_datetime(dt):
...   return datetime.strftime(dt, '%Y-%m-%d')
...
>>> df['date'] = df['date'].apply(convert_datetime)
>>> df.dtypes
date    object
dtype: object
```

Edit:

As you are reading the excel file, better you clean the data at the time of import..

1. `df = pd.read_excel('file_name.xlsx', dtype=str)`
2. `df = pd.read_excel('file_name.xlsx', converters={'col1':str,'date':str})`

Comment: What is the difference between dtype="object" and dtype=str?

Answer (score 0):

Change object type to str type

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2021-08-20']}, dtype="datetime64[ns]")

df["date"] = df["date"].astype(str)
```

and it should work. Tested and returned this:

```
    date
0   2021-08-20
```